# java: why is the implementation code not shown to client

Tags: java, class, interface, client, implementation

Given that i have an interface class, and a separate implementation class. the interface class is shown to the client but not the source code of the implementation class. why is this so? I know one reason is because of encapsulation. are there any more reasons why?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason besides encapsulation that you mentioned is that when a client is developing to an interface instead of a class then they are guaranteed that they can code to their interface as if it were a contract.

The benefit here is it enables code to be more modular and can even promote looser coupling between software classes and components.  Regardless if I even have a proper implementation of the interface or not I might be able to mock expected behavior of the interface in my unit tests so that my unit tests can validate and verify my client code in isolation of a given interface implementation.

This is a powerful thing because it allows developers to more effectively unit test code.  It also allows for developers to more easily work in parallel.  The client developers can code to the interface and unit test it while another developer codes the implementation of the class that implements the interface.  The implementation developer can likewise unit test his class in isolation.

Comment: As he said the Interface can be seen as a contract. A Class implementing the Interface will have to fulfil the contract. Furthermore, the loose coupling when using the Interface is useful, because you are able to change the *implementation* afterwards without having to change the code of the caller itself (e.g., a new name of the implementing class).